an example of an integral domain R which is not a UFD, but R[α] is a UFD where α is an element of fraction field of R.
The reason I find this problem difficult is that I don't no much about fraction fields and UFD.

See the linked dupes for prototypical examples of non-integrally closed quadratic number rings (what sparked Dedekind to develop the foundations of modern number theory and algebra).
